# What's the difference between gcc and clang unordered_map::insert() implementation?

Tags: c++, gcc, stl, clang++, unordered-map

The code below produced different result under gcc and clang. For gcc, X has been copied 10 times, but for clang, it's copied only once, why?

It seems as if different unordered_map::insert() overload had been chosen for gcc and clang. Has the STL standard defined the behavior of this kind of insertion?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

struct X {
  X() {
    std::cout << "construct" << std::endl;
  }
  X(const X& x) {
    std::cout << "copied" << std::endl;
  }
  bool operator==(const X& x) const{
    return true;
  }
};

namespace std {
   template<>
   struct hash<X> {
     std::size_t operator()(const X&x ) const {
       return 0;
     }
   };
}


int main(){
  std::pair<const X, int> e{};
  std::unordered_map<X, int> m;
  for( int i = 0 ; i<10;i++) {
    m.insert(e);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

```
gcc version 8.3.1 20190604
$g++ test.cc -std=c++17 && ./a.out
construct
copied
copied
copied
copied
copied
copied
copied
copied
copied
copied
```

```
Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.4)
$clang++ test.cc -std=c++17 && ./a.out
construct
copied // printed only once
```

And if I make *e* a const, the output will be same for both gcc and clang:

```
const std::pair<const X, int> e{};
```

Comment: `e` is not initialized, leading to UB.

Comment: In C++11 (which you are using) and earlier, the standards permit but do not require elision of temporaries in most cases.  Different strategies for elision of temporaries affects the number of calls of copy constructors (involved in copying a temporary, such as when passing it by value as an argument) and destructors.  Behaviour may also be affected by optimisation settings (which you haven't used).  From C++17, there are more situations where elision of temporaries is mandatory, so less variability of behaviour between compilers (and optimisation settings).

Comment: Add instrumentation for the other special member functions for example adding a copy constructor suppresses the default move constructor.  You might be making the implementations take non-optimal code paths because of suppressed special member functions.  You should add move construction; assignment and move assignment (IIRC).  Remember to make then `noexcept` if this is required for the strong exception guarantee (otherwise copies wiil be done).

Comment: @Peter But it still produced different results if I specified *-std=c++17*

Comment: @RichardCritten I've added move constructor, and it's not called in both cases

Comment: What happens with `std::pair<const X, int> e{};`. Most likely a red herring but then at least there is no undefined behaviour in your code.

Comment: Sorry I rolled back the edit as you pass C++11 on your command line. Probably best if you make the edit to show the behaviour with C++17 (where the copy rules are tightened).

Comment: Live added the extra instrumentation - https://godbolt.org/z/r6rWaEWhT (and some sanity output).

Comment: I believe it's a quality of implementation issue. One implementation first checks whether the element would need to be inserted and only then constructs a node, while the other constructs the node first and then checks. The standard doesn't place any requirements either way, far as I can tell; both implementations are conforming.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik This is strange, because if I make "e" a constant, compiled with gcc, then X will be copied only once too, this behavior can't be explained if the reason is only about the node construction strategy

Comment: Here's what seems to be happening. There are three `insert` overloads: `insert(const value_type&)`, `insert(value_type&&)` and `template <typename P> insert(P&&)`. For const `e`, `insert(const value_type&)` overload is called; this overload can easily check the key first. For non-const `e`, `insert(P&&)` overload is called (it's a better match as it doesn't require qualifying conversion). `insert(P&& p)` is defined as calling `emplace(std::forward<P>(p))` *continued*

Comment: Now, `emplace` just takes a random collection of arguments to pass to `value_type` constructor - it doesn't have a `Key` in hand by itself. So it has to construct a node holding `value_type` before it can even hash the key. That's what causes extra copies, if the rules in the C++ standard are followed literally. Now, how clang avoids those extra copies, I'm not sure. It must have a specialization of `insert` that takes `value_type&`, or else a specialization of `emplace` that does something special when its argument is a flavor of `value_type`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik good point, I'll try to check the clang implementation detailes